# iOS app crash on Tips and Tricks

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The latest version of the app (1.2.2.191) crashes when tapping the 'view tips and tricks' on the about view.

iPhone 4s/iOS 8.1.3, on the chance it's not universal

Comment: Probably some experimental feature, that doesn't work yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - no, I'm pretty sure it used to be a thing. Unless I'm getting confused with a different app.

Comment: Hmm... never noticed it before. Remember what it used to show?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Some app-related tips and tricks! ;-)

Comment: Nothing too exciting from memory, it was a long time ago id have last looked at it. (It could have been broken for months!)

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. I'm rerunning the build.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  Something weird's happening.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - you can check it out now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next release.  There's weird stuff going on with Swift here.

The following code is working in debug builds but not release builds:

```
if let tips = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String] {
    return tips
} else {
    fatalError("Could not load tips at path: \(path)")
}
```

I broke it down one step further and found that this code crashes:

```
if let tips = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
    return tips as [String]
}
```

while this code works:

```
if let tips = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
    println(tips)
    return tips as [String]
}
```

Because that's ugly, I'll be doing this instead:

```
if let tips = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
    return map(tips, { $0 as String })
    // return tips as [String] // This fails in release builds. 
}
```

I'm suspecting that the casting behavior is different between the two builds and that there's a problem with deserialized arrays that they won't cast until fully resolved.  I'll be testing this out in the latest Xcode beta and filing a radar.

Comment: This is fascinating, thanks for the full write up! Now the page opens, I was having a look through - there seems to be a mismatch of black/grey text on the screens which use bullet point lists - thought that probably wasn't worth its own post. Cheers!