# iOS App Crashes when trying to open StackOverflow Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Using the iOS App (version `1.2.2`) on iOS `8.2`. I opened the app without an internet connection (worked fine), but then when I hit the menu button to go to the StackOverflow specific site the app crashed. Upon returning to a place with internet I noticed that all the sites usually listed in the menu were missing, so I logged out and logged back in. Now the app works, except that every time I go to the StackOverflow site from the menu (all other sites do work) the app crashes.

Comment: Try reinstalling the app. By the way, so what is your question?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 No question. This is where they say to report bugs so I felt I should share the story. Idk if it's happened to anyone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  The error I'm getting is `EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN` which as far as I can tell is Swift's way of saying it has no idea what went wrong. I suspect it's similar to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250011/235711) where casting an array failed.

The original code looks like this:

```
func transformItems(items:[AnyObject], type:StacManTagPreferenceType?) -> [StacManTagPreference] {

    let preferences = items as [StacManTagPreference]
    if type != nil {
        return preferences.filter({ $0.tagPreferenceType == type! })
    } else {
        return preferences
    }
}
```

I think this will fix it:

```
let preferences = items.map { $0 as StacManTagPreference }
```

But I really don't want to crash on what really is an optional behavior so I'm doing this:

```
let preferences = items.map { $0 as? StacManTagPreference } .filter { $0 != nil } .map { $0! }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling the app appears to have resolved the issue. Perhaps this is an isolated incident, but just in case it's not hopefully there is a fix simpler than this and that the cause for this can be resolved.